# GameObject is finded as active when it's not active in the hierarchy

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

### So I build a custom class named Obstacles

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Obstacle{

    public GameObject gameObj;
    public Color color;

    public GameObject[] particleEffects;

    public static Vector3 SpawnLocation()
    {
        int positionQuadran = Random.Range(1, 3);
        switch (positionQuadran)
        {
            //spawn above the player
            case 1:
                 return new Vector3(Random.Range(1.5f, -1.5f),
                                                      Random.Range(4f - SpawnStars.closerToPlayer, 4.5f),
                                                      Random.Range(1, -3.2f));
            //spawn benith the player
            case 2:
                return new Vector3(Random.Range(1.5f, -1.5f),
                                                      Random.Range(-0.5f, SpawnStars.closerToPlayer),
                                                      Random.Range(1f, -3.2f));
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Next I created a pool with 6 objects, every two objects with the same color, so there are 3 distinct colors in the `obstaclePool`

The problem is that I am trying to find the inactive `Obstacle`, it works for the first Objects that have a color, but when I ended all the colors and iterate again through the loop it says that the `Obstacle.gameObj` is active in the hierarchy, I don't understand, every `Obstacle.gameObj` is inactive (cuz I set them to be inactive in the `start()` so every Obstacle should have an inactive `Obstacle.gameObj` BUT after I activate the first Obstacle.gameObj the next ones seem to not exist, the loop "finds" only the `gameObj` that are active and assumes that EVERY Object in the list is now active, when actually only the first 3 are active, the remaining 3 are NOT active...And I don't understand why...Why doesn't the code find the remaining `gameObj` as inactive?

```
foreach (Obstacle star in obstaclePool)
{
    if (!star.gameObj.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        Color color = star.color;
        color.a = 0.5f;
        panel.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color; 
        return star;
    }
}
```

Comment: where/when are you using foreach?

Comment: in the Start(){}

Answer (score 0):

Soo I eventually figure it out:
So if I create a costum class like Obstacle I NEED TO MAKE SHORE that if the class has a variable like a GameObject or something that needs to be instantiated or assigned I will do that 
This is how I a eventually solved the problem:

```
        Obstacle go = new Obstacle
        {
            gameObj = Instantiate(prefab.gameObj)
        };
        poolList.Add(go);
```

So we literally create a new Object `Obstacle` and after that we make it's gameObj variable equal with Instantiate(prefab.gameObj), in this way we create every part of the Obstacle.